# Query to compare two rows in MySQL and make an UPDATE

Tags: mysql

I have a table (MySQL) like this:

```
ID    |   AnotherID  |   Number1      |      Number2   |    Data   
1           A             101                 199           Lorem  
2           A             102                 200           
3           A             201                 299                           
4           A             202                 300           Impsun  
5           B             1001                1099  
...
```

Basically, I need to compare in sets of 2 rows and make a SQL Query to achieve this logic:

```
IF row1.anotherID = row2.AnotherID AND
row2.Number1 + row2.Number2 - row1.Number1 - row1.Number2 = 2 AND
row2.ID - row1.ID = 1

THEN

IF some of this 2 rows have the Data field populated and the other row don't 
THEN Copy the Data field into the empty one
ELSE do nothing
```

Final table should be like this

```
ID    |   AnotherID  |   number1      |      number2   |    data   
1           A             101                 199           Lorem  
2           A             102                 200           Lorem
3           A             201                 299           Impsun                
4           A             202                 300           Impsun  
5           B             1001                1099
```

...

How can it be done?
Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you want something like this:

```
update t join
       t t2
       on t.AnotherId = t2.AnotherId and
          t.Number1 + t.Number2 - t2.Number1 - t2.Number2 in (-2, 2) and
          t.id - t2.id in (1, -1)
    set t.data = t2.data
    where t.data is null and t2.data is not null;
```

The idea is to pair each row in `t` with the matching row in `t2` (if any).  Note that the matching row could be above or below, by the logic you give.  That is why the last two conditions are bi-directional.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the answer. What should be t2? Could you give me the exact query if the example table name is "Tbl"? Thanks

Comment: `t2` is a table alias.  The query would start `update tbl t join tbl t2 . . . `.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but the above code give me "0 rows affected" ...

Comment: It works!!! had to replace IS NULL to = '' and IS NOT NULL to != ''

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
select
  ID,
  AnotherID,
  Number1,
  Number2,
  (
    select t2.Data
    from Test t2
    where t2.Data is not null and t2.ID <= t1.ID
    order by t2.ID desc
    limit 1
  ) as SelectedData
from Test t1
order by ID
```

[I created a SQL Fiddle example.](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/01a04/9/0)